# git bash for windows seems to use wrong user name for github SSH connection

Tags: ssh, github, git-bash

I have created a ssh key using my github email address and have added it to github:

[image]

I have also changed my git global email address to use my github email address:

[image]

but when I try to login it says that permission has been denied:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

While there is one piece of your configuration missing from your question, namely your ssh config (which would be in `~/.ssh/config` on linux, but I know not where under Windows/MinGW), I think that the tooling is doing what you ask of it: using your login name, `farha`, as the user name on the remote system.

If you try `ssh -T git@github.com`, you should see something like this:

```
Hi farha! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

That tells you that your key is properly setup with GitHub.

When you clone a repository using `ssh` from GitHub, you will use a repository that looks something like this:

```
git@github.com:farha/REPO.git
```

Note the `git` at the front.

Alternatively, you could put a stanza in your equivalent to the linux `~/.ssh/config` for github:

```
Host github.com
  User git
```